# Editing related records in ArcGIS JavaScript API 4.27

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

[image]

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/release-notes/

According to these link, there is an upgrade on ArcGIS JavaScript API. This new version 4.27 provide editing related records but it does not work on my data. Although I added the related owner table to my parcel data, this table does not appear when I open the editor widget on my web map. What is the problem with my data or code? How can I fix them?

```
const aa = new FeatureLayer({
            title: "Saaaa",
            
                    "https://services8.arcgis.com/zV6Gi1eBQ6jaZOKX/arcgis/rest/services/owner/FeatureServer",
          });
const Parcels = new FeatureLayer({
            title: "Subdivision Parcels",
            
            url :  "https://arcgis2.mipmap.nl/server/rest/services/Hosted/owner/FeatureServer",
                    //" https://services8.arcgis.com/zV6Gi1eBQ6jaZOKX/arcgis/rest/services/owner/FeatureServer ",
            listMode: "hide-children",
              elevationInfo: {
                mode: "on-the-ground",
                // offset: 0.5,
                // unit: "meters"
            },
            renderer: {
              type: "simple",
              symbol: {
                type: "polygon-3d",
                symbolLayers: [
                  {
                    type: "fill",
                    material: { color: [255, 237, 204, 0.5] },
                    outline: { color: [133, 108, 62, 0.5] }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            popupTemplate : {
                // autocasts as new PopupTemplate()
                title: "Attributes",
                content: [
                  {
                    type: "fields",
                    fieldInfos: [
                      {
                        fieldName: "{parcelnumb}",
                        label: "Parcel Number"
                      },
                      {
                        fieldName: "parcelland",
                        label: "Parcel Land Use"
                      },
                      {
                        fieldName: "shape_Area",
                        label: "Parcel Area"
                      },
                      {
                        fieldName: "plancode",
                        label: "Plan Code"
                      },
                    ]
                  },
                
                  
                  ],
              },
          });

const drawBuilding = {
        layer: [Parcels, tableList],
        formTemplate: {
   
     elements: [
    
       {   
    type: "relationship",
    displayType : "list",
    // Relationship ID on the feature service is 1
    relationshipId: 0,
  
  
    displayCount: 3,
    
    orderByFields: [
      {
        field: "owner",
        order: "desc"
      }
    ],
    type: "fields",
  fieldInfos: [
  {
      fieldName: "owner",
      label: "Parcel Number"
  }],

     }] 
    },
        

   };
```

Comment: Does it only fail for your Enterprise hosted data (which isn't supported yet), but work for your ArcGIS Online hosted data?
--- See this and other "Known limitations" in https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Editor.html